# Active MQ Producer hangs indefinitely on send() method

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using active mq producer-subscriber model in asynchronous mode to write a simple test program. I am running my consumer code first and then producer code. While cosumer runs fine, producer code hangs indefinitely while calling the send() method. I am giving relevant code snippets below :

Producer Class:

```
public void produce() {

    try {
        con = MyConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        dest = session.createQueue("som.mq");
        producer = session.createProducer(dest);
        con.start();
        File file = new File("Message.xml");
        message = session.createObjectMessage();
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        message.setObject(buffer);
        producer.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught " + e);
    }

}
```

Consumer Class:

```
public void consume() {

    try {
        con = MyConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        dest = session.createQueue("som.mq");
        consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);
        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                        ObjectMessage myMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
                        byte[] myByte = (byte[]) myMessage.getObject();
                        for (int i = 0; i < myByte.length; i++) {
                            System.out.print((char) myByte[i]);
                        }
                    } else
                        System.out.println(message);
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Caught JMS Exception " + ex);
                }
            }
        };
        session.setMessageListener(listener);
        con.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught " + e);
    }
}
```

MyConnection Class

```
public class MyConnection {

private static transient MyConnection myConnection;
private PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private Connection connection;

private MyConnection() {

        String url = "tcp://localhost:61616";
        connectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(url);
        connectionFactory.setMaxConnections(8);

}

public static MyConnection getInstance() {
    if (myConnection == null) {
        synchronized (MyConnection.class) {
            if (myConnection == null) {
                myConnection = new MyConnection();
            }
        }

    }
    return myConnection;
}

public Connection getConnection() throws JMSException {
    System.out.println("Printing connection "+connectionFactory.createConnection().toString());
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    return connection;
}

}
```

I get no exceptions on console output. Appreciate someone letting me know what I might be missing or coding incorrectly.

Comment: Check firewall settings if not blocked

Comment: @MarmiK No firewall present. This code was working fine before 1) I made MyConnection a singleton and 2) Used a listener on Consumer class instead of just receive() method. On Active MQ console I can see the messages piling up on the queue but not being consumed.